# How to set response in variable of array type in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to store response data in a variable coming from the API response & show it in component.html file.

**Component.ts file :**

```
public coinsHistory = [];
this.service.getCoinsHistory().subscribe(
    (response) => {
        this.handleCoinsResponse(response);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
handleCoinsResponse(response: any) {
    console.log('what  ------', response);
    this.spinner.show();
    if (response.status === 1) {
        this.coinsHistory = response.responseData.data;
        console.log(' this.coinsHistory ------', typeof(this.coinsHistory));
    }
}
```

**and in component.html file:**

```
<div *ngFor="let coinData of coinsHistory">
    <p>{{ coinData.coins_earned_for }}</p>
    <p>{{ coinData.referral_coins }}</p>
</div>
```

**Data from api is like this:**

```
status: 1
msgCode: 224
msg: "Referrer coins history"
responseData:
    total_coins: 200
    data: Array(2)
        0:
            id: 85
            referrer_id: 4
            referee_id: null
            coins_earned_for: "Deducted for withdraw"
            referral_coins: "-100"
            created_at: "2020-02-01 12:18:21"
            updated_at: "2020-02-01 12:18:21"

        1:
            id: 85
            referrer_id: 4
            referee_id: null
            coins_earned_for: "Deducted for withdraw"
            referral_coins: "-100"
            created_at: "2020-02-01 12:18:21"
            updated_at: "2020-02-01 12:18:21"
```

**But I got error says:**

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Comment: The only mistake I see in your code is that you were wrong to write coinsHistory instead of coinHistory on the ngFor and in handleResponse

Comment: Ahh sorry that was writing mistake in question. Please ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the response with a model instead of any, for example:

```
export interface ICoinsHistory{
totalCoins: number;
data: ICoin[];
}
export interface ICoin{
//...Coin data
}
```

Comment: Is defining interface is necessary. What if I don't want to? Is there any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly you don't necessarily need an interface, please check your data structures and variable names.

Take a look at this stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2gbvb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: It's working there but I don't know why it doesn't work for me.